# What is the working out to find "b" in the triangle below?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, circles

The image is attached to this link  https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVfOR.png [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVfOR.png). What is the working out to find "b"? I understand that I need to find an angle in the triangle but what steps can I take to first of all get an angle in the triangle? From this, I will be able to use trig to find b.

[image]

Comment: $1$ radians is the angle when the arc is equal to the radius, so in this case
the angle is $1/2$ radians, and $b=2\sin 0.5\approx 0.96$

Answer (score 0):

The circumference of the sector $s = r \theta$, where $\theta$ is in radians. Since you know both $s$ and $r$ you can find $\theta$.

Comment: Why the downvote? this is correct.

Comment: Usually this happens when someone believes that the question does not have sufficient context, so no one should answer until the context has been added in. I believe the OP has shown some effort, which does not have to mean showing their working-out.